# Cannot remote copy file via tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, scp

I'm trying to get a file from server1 (localhost) with scp.
I am accessing server1 from the gateway server2 (that is the only one accessible from the internet).

I am able to open a ssh connection by using:

```
ssh -p 2222 -L 8080:localhost:443 myUser@server2
```

And by googling I found that the scp command should be something like:

```
scp -P 2222 myUser@127.0.0.1:/sourcePathToFile/file destinationPathToFile
```

But what I get is

```
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2222: Connection refused
```

These are the entries in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   server3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could those with an off-topic fetish please consider the SEO implications? el-Goog didn't read your memo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both of these commands are being executed on server1...

If you can log in to server2 using the ssh options you listed above, (connecting to port 2222 on server2), then you should be able to copy the file using

```
scp -P 2222 /sourcePathToFile/file myUser@server2:/destinationPathToFile
```

(Unless I'm missing the purpose of forwarding your own local port 8080 to remote port 443, which is the effect of the **-L 8080:localhost:443** portion of your ssh command.)

The problem with your scp command was that it was attempting to connect to an ssh server running on server1 on port 2222, when it should be connecting to the ssh server running on server2 on port 2222.